# Correct way to define class method and property in Ruby class

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a `Person` class in Ruby which has some methods and properties. The below is how I have implemented it now.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :gender, :mother

  def initialize(name, gender, mother)
    @name = name
    @gender = gender
    @mother = mother
    @spouse = nil
  end

  def add_spouse(spouse)
    if spouse
      @spouse = spouse
      spouse.spouse = self
    end
  end
  
  def father(self)
    return [self.mother.spouse]
  end
end
```

I want to access the methods like this:

```
m = Person.new('mom', 'Female')
d = Person.new('dad', 'Male')

d.add_spouse(m)

p = Person.new('Jack', 'Male', m)
```

If I want to get the `father` of `p`, then I want to get it like this: `p.father`.

So is the above implementation correct?

I am getting the below error if I run the code:

```
person.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected `self', expecting ')'
  def father(self)
person.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input
```

If I remove `self` from `def father(self)`, then I am getting this error:

```
person.rb:14:in `add_spouse': undefined method `spouse=' for #<Person:0x00005570928382d8> (NoMethodError)
```

My error was here: `attr_accessor :spouse`. I had to add this and to access it I had to do `puts(p.father[0].name)`

Is there a better way to implement the above class with similar other properties like `father`, `children`, `brothers` etc?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I have added the errors in the question.

Comment: This is really more a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? "Better" is subjective, however, [so] only allows objective questions. You need to give a precise, unambiguous, objectively measurable definition of "betterness" in order to make the question objective. It would also help if you could explain your code a little. Why does the `father` method return an array? How many fathers do you expect a person to have? Is it *always* true that a person's father is the mother's current spouse, i.e. if the mother re-marries, then the father changes, and if the mother dies, the father dies, too?

Comment: @JörgWMittag By better way I meant whether to use `self.some_variable` or `@some_variable` because I saw both examples. For `father` it is always the `mother`'s current spouse. Well that is how I want atleast initially. Also by better I meant like in python to get method as a property in python we use `@property`. So in ruby should I use anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, everything is an object, well *almost* everything *excluding blocks, etc*. Ruby uses `classes` as *definitions* for `Objects` and they establish `attributes` and `methods`.

Your code sets the attributes for `name`, `gender` and `mother` and has methods for `add_spouse` and `father`. So there's an obvious mix for father being *interpreted* as both attribute and method. From a naming convention perspective we could rename that method `collect_father_relation` or something similar, which will process the logic to present the Object.

You also do not need to explicitly write `return` as you have in the `father` method, Ruby does that for you.

I would reconfigure the `father` method to the below:

```
def collect_father_relation
  @mother&.spouse
end
```

You call the `@mother` instance_variable, defined the instance, and only call `spouse` if `@mother` is present (as it can be `nil`) with the `&.` operator.

You should also prepare the `initialize` function for a `nil` mother being passed:

```
def initialize(name, gender, mother = nil)
```

This will accept a mother parameter, but also not raise an `ArgumentError` if one is not passed.

Finally, you will have to add an `attr_accessor` for `:spouse` as you will want to explicitly reference `spouse` for the spouse Person object as you are setting the relation in `spouse.spouse = self`

Other comments:

Let's make a guard clause for the `add_spouse` method (as we have above) to explicitly explain what we are doing, rather than the ambiguous if statement.

```
  def add_spouse(spouse)
    return if spouse.nil?
    
    @spouse = spouse
    spouse.spouse = self
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look -

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :gender, :mother, :spouse

  def initialize(name, gender, mother)
    @name = name
    @gender = gender
    @mother = mother
    @spouse = nil
  end

  def add_spouse(spouse)
    if spouse
      @spouse = spouse
      @spouse.spouse = self
    end
  end
  
  def father()
    return [self.mother.spouse]
  end
end
```

output -

```
m = Person.new('mom', 'Female', nil)
d = Person.new('dad', 'Male', nil)
d.add_spouse(m)
p = Person.new('Jack', 'Male', m)
```

As written in a comment, it's more a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/